# PHP namespaces in project subfolders

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, namespaces, autoload

I've been struggling a bit with namespaces in PHP lately. Beginning a new project in an object oriented fashion, I want to prepare the project neat and clean from the structure to the functionnality.

As I said, it is developped in object oriented PHP. Using **Doctrine** as ORM, the global structure of the project looks like this :

```
/admin
  |- /index.php
/css
/fonts
/img
/js
/src
  |- /controller
  |- /model
  |- /system
    |- /utils
      |- /Singleton.php
  |- /view
/vendor
/index.php
```

Ok, so let's take a quick example.

I have the Singleton class which lies in the following path : src/system/utils/Singleton.php

```
<?php

namespace system\utils;

/**
 * Base class for singleton use cases
 */
class Singleton 
{
    /**
     * Returns the *Singleton* instance of this class.
     * @staticvar Singleton $instance The *Singleton* instance of this class.
     * @return Singleton the *Singleton* instance.
     */
    public static function getInstance() {
        static $instance = null;
        if ($instance === null) {
            $instance = new static();
        }
        return $instance;
    }

   // Private constructor, only local construction allowed
    protected function __construct() {
    }

    // Private cloner, only current instance 
    private function __clone() {
    }

    // Private wakeup function, to prevent unserializing
    private function __wakeup() {
    }
}
```

As you can see, this class uses the namespace `system\utils`.
Then, in the `/index.php` file in the main folder, to use this class I do the following :

```
<?php
  require_once 'bootstrap.php';
  use system\utils\Singleton;

  $singleton = Singleton::getInstance();
  var_dump($singleton);
?>
```

*(Note : the `bootstrap.php` is the configuration file for Doctrine. I know it uses some kind of autoloading, and that probably could be a part of the problem I'm exposing here, so you can find the content of it at the end of this post)*

This example works perfectly fine. Great.
BUT. If I do the exact same test not in `/index.php` but `/admin/index.php`, it fails and PHP says it can't find the class Singleton.

I'm getting really confused here, because I thought namespaces were some kind of "unique" identifier for each class in a project architecture and then could be used to retrieve one class anywhere in the structure of the project. Obviously, I was wrong and googling around that didn't help me at all.

My best guess goes towards autoloading and that kind of stuff, since I know Doctrine uses it. Maybe I missed something while configuring the ORM. As I said earlier, here is the content of my `/bootstrap.php` containing all the configuration settings.

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

// Create a simple "default" Doctrine ORM configuration for Annotations
$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src/model/entities/"), $isDevMode);

// database configuration parameters
$conn = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host' => 'host',
    'port' => 'port',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'dbname' => 'database',
    'user' => 'database',
    'password' => 'database'
);

// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

I don't know if this could help, but I can use namespaces correctly anywhere inside the /src folder but it seems like it doesn't work in another subfolder of the main directory.

If someone has a clear explanation about what happens here and how namespaces should be managed in PHP, and eventually how I could apply corrections to my code, it'd be really nice of you to share your knowledge.

---

**EDIT :**

Okay so it definitely has to do with autoloading. I managed to get it working by writing the correct `use` statement for the namespace AND declaring an `__autoload` function requiring files once in `../src/`.

```
<?php
    use system\utils\Singleton;

    $singleton = Singleton::getInstance();
    $singleton->manageSession();

    function __autoload($className)
    {
        echo "Autoloading $className.php in ../src/";
        require_once("../src/$className.php");
    }

    require_once '../bootsrap.php';
?>
```

This outputs `Autoloading system\utils\Singleton.php in ../src/`

So it works and I can continue with that solution. The thing is I see that as a workaround, not a solution. I still believe I'm doing something wrong and it could be optimized, but can't figure out how... If you have some knowledge to share on this, I'm all ears!

---

Thanks a bunch in advance and sorry for the big post. If you need any kind of additional info, just ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing exactly the same in the admin/index.php, which in this case is wrong.

The issue lies at the following line:

```
require_once 'bootstrap.php';
```

This tells php look for the file `bootstrap.php` first relative to the file which is including/requiring the file and if that fails, in the configured include paths.

It's not included in your directory structure, but from the looks of it, `bootstrap.php` sits at the same level as `index.php`. To fix your issue replace the above line in `admin/index.php` with the following:

```
require_once '../bootstrap.php';
```

Comment: I am so dumb. `index.php` is indeed at the same level as `bootstrap.php`. It worked with my custom autoload function in my edit of the post because I did required the bootstrap file as `../bootstrap.php` instead of `bootstrap.php`, as you said. So, actually, I already applied your fix without knowing it... But either was I really dumb at that moment, or my brain farted a little. Just to be sure, retried it with `../bootstrap.php` in which I removed my custom `_autoload` function and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your time and considering helping a lost soul like me!